# Start activity inside tabhost in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a tabbed activity as shown below. I need to call a MapsActivity inside first tab("Search") which extends FragmentActivity. Any help in resolving this would help.

```
public class TabbedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);

        TabHost tab = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tab.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = tab.newTabSpec("Search");
        spec1.setIndicator("Search");
        spec1.setContent(R.id.layout1);
        tab.addTab(spec1);

        TabHost.TabSpec spec2 = tab.newTabSpec("Settings");
        spec2.setIndicator("Settings");
        spec2.setContent(R.id.layout2);
        tab.addTab(spec2);
    }
}
```

Tried this solution, but shows error "MapsActivity is not an enclosing class"

```
tab.addTab(tab.newTabSpec("Search")
    .setIndicator("Search")
    .setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {

    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        return new TextView(MapsActivity.this);
    }
}));
```

Comment: Replace `MapsActivity` by `TabbedActivity`.

Comment: But How do I call MapsActivity then ? I have to call MapsActivity from this TabbedActivity class inside the tab

Answer (score 0):

Activities-in-tabs has been deprecated as a technique for nearly **six years**.

Do something else, such as:

- `FragmentTabHost`, with fragments for your tabs, such as `MapFragment`
- `ViewPager`, with fragments for pages (`MapFragment`, `SupportMapFragment`) and a tabbed indicator (`TabLayout`, `PagerTabStrip`, etc.)